# Why doesn't htop show my docker-processes using wsl2

Tags: docker-for-windows, wsl-2

Building my container using docker and wsl2 I wanted to see what happens. Running `htop` in wsl only shows the CPU usage, but none processes running in my containers.

The only information searching for `htop`, `docker` and `wsl2`, the only thing I could find was this archived and unrelated reddit-thread: https://www.reddit.com/r/bashonubuntuonwindows/comments/dia2bw/htop_on_wsl2_doesnt_show_any_processes_while_ps/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Docker does not run in your default WSL-distro, but in a special Docker-Wsl-distro. Running `wsl -l` shows the installed distros:

```
Ubuntu (Standard)
docker-desktop
docker-desktop-data
```

Docker desktop is based on alpine and you can run `top` right out of the box:

```
wsl -d docker-desktop top
```

If you want `htop`, you need to install it first:

```
wsl -d docker-desktop apk update 
wsl -d docker-desktop apk add htop
```

Running

```
wsl -d docker-desktop htop
```

will now give you a nice overview of what is happening in your docker-containers:

[image: htop showing docker processes]

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Morty.

The following commands give you the list for windows

```
wsl -l
```

Then you can run either of the following command

```
wsl -d  docker-desktop ps
wsl -d  docker-desktop top
```